# Wireless not working in spite of following every locatable work-around

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, ndiswrapper

I have a Broadcom 802.11 wireless pci card in my laptop, chipset 4318. I have followed all the instructions to replace the delivered driver with ndiswrapper with the appropriate Windows driver bcmwl5. I've just loaded Ubuntu so the kernel is 3.5.0-17. I had to use ndiswrapper-1.58rc1 to circumvent a problem with modprobe but now when I follow all the steps given for install ndiswrapper I get no errors but still no luck. Driver b43-pci-bridge is listed in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf but it is still the driver associated with the device according to lshw and I can't find any reference as to where that association is being made. When Ubuntu boots the wireless assistant button on the keyboard is not lit and I can't find any combination of keys or command to get it to light, I assume because the installed driver is wrong. So in short Ubuntu help - Wireless trouble shooting has used up the better part of 3 days but still not produced the desired outcome. Any ideas? I'm sure that if I could find out where that driver is being associated with the device I could make ndiswrapper work instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ndiswrapper is the least desirable option, in my opinion. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: you are a genius. It works fine. So why all this fuss on so many sites about ndiswrapper? (rhetorical question of course) If I had found this solution I wouldn't have wasted 3 days

Comment: Many seemingly reliable authorities don't actually understand Broadcom devices as they are driven in Linux in 2013. I barely understand myself because a new chip seems to come out every week, including one new one that has NO way to get working, not even ndiswrapper. I am aware of no Broadcom for which ndiswrapper is the best answer.

Comment: After I installed the latest updates I now have to re-issue sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43 every time I re-boot. Any ideas what needs to be plugged?

Comment: Please try this terminal sequence: sudo su; echo b43 >> /etc/modules; exit. Does it work now?

Comment: nope, still not working

Comment: Does b43 load on boot without manual intervention now? lsmod Is there some other blacklist? cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf or ls /etc/modprobe.d